# Arrangement of 5 letters with a specific order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

how to calculate the arrangement of the 5 letters a,b,c,d,e when a,b,c must be in the written order: abcde,adbce,daebc,...

I know the answer is 20 by another way but want to know what's wrong with my following method:

OOaOObOOcOO so we need to select 2 place of from the 8 'o's ,that's the combination  c(8,2) and considering their order we have 2!*c(8,2) .
I know that's wrong but don't know why!

Comment: Surely, it is easier to select one of the five positions for the d and one of the remaining four places for the e, after which the a, b, and c can only be placed in one way.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong because the four choices

```
dOaOObOOcOe
dOaOObOOceO
OdaOObOOcOe
OdaOObOOceO
```

all give the same final order, but your method counts them as distinct.

Comment: thanks,that's helpful. now how to calculate the exact number? I mean how to trim the redundancy

Comment: @mahyarp I would come at it from a different angle. For instance, start with `OaObOcO`, then pick one of the four spaces to put `OdO`, then pick one of the (now five) spaces to put an `e`. Or count the cases where `d, e`are adjacent separate from the cases where they are not. Or note that when taking all the the $5! = 120$ possible arrangements without restrictions, and then rearranging `a, b. c` within each of them to alphabetic order, they go neatly into groups of $3! = 6$ who have all become equal. So there are $\frac{120}6 = 20$ different groups.

Comment: thanks a lot , and please say if the modified answer of mine is correct.                      ( - )a( - )b( -)c( - ) , we can choose one of the double places and put 'e' and 'c' in it. that's c(4,1)*c(2,2)2!  or choose two of the double places and put the remaining letters in them separately that's c(4,2)*c(2,1)*c(2,1)*2! divided by 2!*2! for handling the repetition .

Comment: @mahyarp That lookos good. I would personally treat them as single places capable of holding two letters rather than double places, though. It gets rid of a lot of the unnecessary terms.